# Big query throwing invalid errors on load jobs

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a regularly scheduled load job that runs and imports data into bigQuery via the json data format every hour. This process has been working fine for months,now all of a sudden bigQuery has started to throw me back errors about missing required fields.

Naturally the first thing I did was review my schema and compare to one of the JSON files and all required fields are indeed there. Bigquery doesn't throw much information back beyond that, and I have checked and re-checked my data 20 times because I'm usually missing something.

Is this a back-end issue? or perhaps formatting requirements have changed? A perfect example would be JOB # **job_2ee5a4be176c421985d7c3eaa84abf4b**.It tells me "missing required field(s)", of which there are only 4 in my schema - I check my JSON for this particular job and they are all there.

Any light shed on this would be tremendously helpful, thanks in advance!!

A sample of the json, only the first 4 fields are required in my schema, and they are all there! I have also double-checked to make sure no extra fields are in the json, and each json is on a new line etc.:

`{"date":"2013-05-31 20:56:41","sdate":1370033801,"type":"0","act":"1","cid":"139","chain":"5156","hotel":"21441","template":"default","arrival":"2013-08-04 00:00:00","depart":"2013-08-05 00:00:00","window":"64","nights":"1","total":"0.0000","dailyrate":"0.0000","session":"1530894334","source":"google","keyword":"the carolina hotel chapel hill nc","campaign":"organic","medium":"organic","visits":"2","device":"pc","language":"en-us","ip":"gc.synxis.com","cookies":"2","base_total":"0.0000","base_rate":"0.0000","batch":"batch_1370045767"}`

Comment: Hi there!  I work on this feature at Google.  I'm taking a look at your problem now -- there's recently been a change to the way JSON importing works, and it's likely related what you're experiencing.

Comment: It looks like you have 5 required fields -- one is called "currencies"?  And is not set here?  I'm trying to understand why the old code would have accepted this without complaining.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks so much for looking into this! My currency field is a nested record that is (was) nullable. Do you think the change means that all nested records now have to be indicated somehow?

Comment: No, `NULLABLE` record fields should still be fine to omit.  I don't have an easy way of looking at the schema and its history, but the logs from the failing job indicate that "currencies" is a required field in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Google engineer who works on BigQuery.  Sorry for the trouble; it appears that you're missing a required `RECORD` field called `currencies`.

It appears that the old code was accepting this due to a bug.  It was creating empty `RECORD` fields even if one was not specified in the JSON.  As a result, a `RECORD` field that was `REQUIRED` could be omitted without triggering an error.  However, the correct behavior is to trigger an error, which is what the current code does.

It is unfortunate that the error message does not tell you *which* required field was missing.  This is a TODO in the current version of the code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I made the changes and it works now. I didn't realize the nested records couldn't really be nullable - I had not specified them as required in my schema so I am assuming they are required by default? Regardless, thanks so much for your help! I hope others find this useful.

Comment: Glad this was helpful!  A teammate tells me that you should be able to update your schema and set the record field to `NULLABLE`.  This would let you continue to import as you were before.

Comment: Hi @JoshHaberman. I see that this TODO is left exactly where it was a year ago. It's very unfortunate - imagine a schema that goes beyond a toy example with dozen of required and optional fields. How exactly should we guess which one of "missing required field(s)" is missing? 

Will it be possible to raise the priority of this TODO?

Comment: @Roman: Sorry for the delay -- I've just checked in a change that will list the missing fields explicitly.  This should go live when we push our next release sometime next week.  Cheers, Josh

Comment: @Roman: you're welcome! Just a heads-up that this fix might not get deployed for another week or two, since we have Google I/O coming up.